# Exchange 2007/Outlook 2010 Clients not auto-updating inbox

Tags: windows-7, exchange-2007, outlook-2010

Recently uesrs have been complaining that they are not getting new emails. Upon investigation i realized that the `last updated` time on the inbox was from a while ago and users now have to manually send and receive and sometimes will need to restart outlook before the inbox will update.

Any ideas what would be causing this?

Comment: Are these users using Outlook cached mode?  When the inbox isn't updating does Outlook still say it is "Connected to Microsoft Exchange"?

Comment: It does say "connected to Microsoft Exchange" 
It is in cached mode, In server mode it connects the same way.

Comment: I to am seeing the same issue.  Any fixes found?  I thought it was a bad NIC and now the problem is appearing in other areas.

Comment: Question, Are these users trying to open more then one mailbox at a time? In other words, are they opening their mailbox as well as someone elses mailbox as well. Look for 9646 events in the application log of the Server http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb676486(EXCHG.80).aspx  http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/outlook/thread/46e773da-1d93-4cb8-886e-51bbebff585e

Comment: Yes some of them do have multiple mailboxes open. They are using Outlook 2010 which allows multiple separate Exchange Mailboxes

Comment: I did some virus cleanups and updated my SBS box with the latest updates and the issue seems to have mostly dissipated, but I'm still not 100% sure why